# Check SP datetime control is empty or not

Tags: jquery, date-time, datepicker

I want to check whether a  Sharepoint datetime control is empty or not. How can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint's OOB Date time control, I am assuming below would be the mark up.

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeControl ID = "StartDate" runat = "server"></SharePointWebControls:DateTimeControl>
```

So now in order to validate this field we can use jQuery.

**1.** Understand how this SharePoint control is rendered in browser. It will be something like below.

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$StartDate$StartDateDate" class="ms-input" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_StartDate_StartDateDate" type="text" maxlength="45" autopostback="0">
```

**2.**
Point to note is the name of the control is rendered as `StartDateDate`. So we can utilise this and get value of the control using jQuery.

**3.**
Store the value in a variable and check for empty.

```
var startDateValue = jQuery("input[name$='StartDateDate']").val().trim()
//Check for empty 
//Check for Start Date
if (startDateValue == '') {
    alert('Empty');
}
else {
    alert('Not Empty');
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I am using this Control
     
    <sharepoint:datetimecontrol id="dtfrom" dateonly="true" runat="server"></sharepoint:datetimecontrol>

Comment: I guess it should work. Can you see what's the name and id you get for this control in browser using F12 developer tool.?

Comment: Np. Happy to help :)